# Deselect a text box in jQuery after page reload if content is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Google Instant style jQuery search script that queries a PHP file then parses the results into an HTML div. When no query is active the text box is automatically selected but when a query is active I want it not to be automatically selected. I know this is possible to do by using the `.blur();` function, but how can I make it only use the `.blur();` function when a query is active and the page has been reloaded? I hope everyone can understand my question.

My jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id^=type_]').click(function () {
        type = this.id.replace('type_', '');
        $('[id^=type_]').removeClass('selected');
        $('#type_' + type).addClass('selected');
        return false;
    });
    $('#query').focus();
    if (window.location.hash != "") {
        var full = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
        var queryType = full.substring(0, full.indexOf("/"));
        $('#type_' + queryType).click();
    } else {
        $('#type_search').click();
    }
    $('#query').keyup(function () {
        var query = $(this).val();
        var url = '/' + type + '/' + query + '/';
        window.location.hash = '' + type + '/' + query + '/';
        document.title = $(this).val() + ' - My Search Script';
        $('#results').show();
        if (query == '') {
            window.location.hash = '';
            document.title = 'My Search Script';
            $('#results').hide();
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (results) {
                $('#results').html(results);
            }
        });
    });
    if (window.location.hash.indexOf('#' + type + '/') == 0) {
        query = window.location.hash.replace('#' + type + '/', '').replace('/', '');
        $('#query').val(decodeURIComponent(query)).keyup();
    }
});
```

Comment: by "query is active" do you mean the url having #video/whatnot in it? or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after reviewing the source I found that my suspicion was correct.  Because there is only one text box on the page, once you blur the query one, it just goes back to it.  You can make another input node on your html page e.g.

```
<input type="text" style="display:none" id="invisible">
```

and then use this code

```
if ($('#query').val().length) {
    $('#invisible').focus();
}
```

and that should get you there :)

Comment: and that would be because it's the only input on the site. with two it *should* work.

Answer (score 0):

Ahha! I see what you mean.  You can check if the textbox has anything in it with the .val() function in JQuery. Assuming that '#query' is the textbox, you can change that part to

```
if($('#query').val().length == 0)
$('#query').focus();
```

Comment: rats XD hm... do you have a test site up that you can post publically?

Comment: I found the problem... I'll make another answer for clarity